# backup mysql database by calling a batch file through php

Tags: php, mysql

I failed with the mysqldump method earlier. Now I'm trying to just call the batch file which will call the mysqldump.
The php file which calls the batch file, looks something like this:

```
<?php
shell_exec('c:\\abc.bat');

?>
```

And the batch file, which when I execute directly yields the 7kb sql file that I'm expecting:

```
mysqldump --opt -u root -ppassword onstor > c:\onstordb.sql
```

But when I use php to execute it, I get a 0 Kb file, I wonder why. I tried both shell_exec and exec. Is there something wrong with the parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php#85930

It reads:

> I was having trouble using the PHP
>   `exec` command to execute any batch
>   file.   Executing other commands
>   (i.e., "dir") works fine).  But if I
>   executed a batch file, I receieved no
>   output from the `exec` command.
>
> The server setup I have consists of
>   Windows Server 2003 server running
>   IIS6 and PHP 5.2.3.  On this server, I
>   have:
>
> 1. Granted execute permissions to the Internet User  on
>      `c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe`.
> 2. Granted Everyone->Full Control to the directory in which the batch file
>      is written.
> 3. Granted Everyone->Full Control on the entire `c:\cygwin\bin` directory
>      and its contents.
> 4. Granted the Internet User "log on as batch" permissions.
> 5. Specified the full path to each file being executed.
> 6. Tested these scripts running from the command line on the server and
>      they work just fine.
> 7. Ensured that `%systemroot%\system32` is in the
>      system path.
>
> It turns out that even with all of the
>   above in place on the server, I had to
>   specify the full path to `cmd.exe` in
>   the `exec` call.
>
> When I used the call:
>
> ```
> $output = exec("c:\\windows\\system32\\cmd.exe /c $batchFileToRun");
> ```
>
> then everything worked fine.  In my
>   situation, `$batchFileToRun` was the
>   actual system path to the batch file
>   (i.e., the result of a call to
>   `realpath()`).

Comment: please do not just paste links for answers. if you want to do that, consider making them comments. Make the answer more valuable by putting some words to it and summarizing or quoting from the provided link in case the remote site goes away or is temporary unavailable.

Comment: If php.net goes away, may god have mercy on our souls.

Comment: @Dampe I had that happen on at least one occasion. php.net was down and the supplied link wasn't working for some time, which left the OP wondering. Of course, providing a link to the mirror fixed that, but nonetheless.

Comment: Gordon, quoting a meaningful portion (enough to make sense) is copyright infringement in most cases. In the case of the PHP manual it is available under a CC attribution license, so copying is only allowed with attribution. Copying from a webpage that doesn't publish a permissive license is plain illegal.

Comment: Not in this case, as it comes from comments, however. There are many ways to skin this cat. How about the fact that it took me 2 seconds to find this by doing a find on "bat" in the docs. Call me GoogleS8N.

Comment: @Dan I'm just telling the best practise for links in answers. Please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7515/why-is-linking-bad and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers for a discussion. This, of course, does not mean people should disobey any content licensing issues. Be sensible. Add value.